# Как узнать изготовителя видеокарты NVidia?

Tags: c#, nvidia

Подскажите, как узнать изготовителя видеокарты NVidia на C#? Под изготовителем подразумевается производитель видеокарты (msi,evga,asus и т.д.), а не чипа и не ее модель.

Win32_VideoController,NvAPI - такой информации не дают.

Comment: Не знаю, оно или нет, но [вот что нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42249529/12888024)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Линуксах можно получить производителя в `lspci -v`

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 36fa
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39
    Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at f8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Строки берутся из файла https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/v2.2/pci.ids у которого структура

```
# Vendors, devices and subsystems. Please keep sorted.

# Syntax:
# vendor  vendor_name
#   device  device_name             <-- single tab
#       subvendor subdevice  subsystem_name <-- two tabs
```

subvendor subdevice - можно увидить и в диспечере устройств Windows как айди оборудования, расшифровка которого https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/identifiers-for-pci-devices

```
s(4) is the four-character vendor-defined subsystem identifier.

n(4) is the four-character PCI SIG-assigned identifier for the vendor of the subsystem.
```

Нужно смотреть на байты n и s(особенно n), и по ним определите вендора самой платы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
67ff  Baffin [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
    1002 0b04  Radeon RX 560
```

На этой картинке вендор AMD - под рукой нет примера с виндой..

```
PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1B06&SUBSYS_360A1462&REV_A1
                                 ^^^^
```

- 1462 - это MSI.

Сабвендор может быть не заполнен производителем - тогда subsys совпадает c ven dev

Для радеонов список вендоров есть в этом faq

https://www.amd.com/ru/support/kb/faq/gpu-55

Получить список устройств в c# можно через ManagementObjectSearcher

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
```

Comment: Возможно я слепой, но что-то я не вижу здесь изготовителя видеокарты, можно ткнуть меня носом?

Comment: @andreymal  Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 36fa в примере lspci.

Comment: А впрочем да, загуглил pci id и всё норм (хотя на одном из моих линуксов всё равно никакого Subsystem не отобразилось почему-то)

Comment: Неа, так не выйдет 
PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1B06&SUBSYS_360A1462&REV_A1 - кто по вашему производитель?

Comment: такого нет в списке линуксов) а есть пятилетняя карточка для примера? список винды где-то видел, вспомню - дополню

Comment: 10de - NVIDIA Corporation
 1B06 - GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] ну как бы это не то

Comment: @Zud71 - 1462 это MSI

Comment: А это уже интересно )))

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вендоров нашел тут https://gist.github.com/cuteribs/0a4d85f745506c801d46bea22b554f7d

Comment: @Zud71 список коротковат =) в pci.ids вендоров побольше

Comment: @eri меня интересуют только производители видеокарт так, что список еще придется урезать ))))